# How to find out if a variable is blank

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a function which does not work.
I dont know what the syntax will be when I want to find out if the variable is not blank and then display/write  the variable??

```
function contactUsMailer(e) {
try {
var recipient = "test@test.dk";
var timestamp = e.values[0];
var email = e.values[1];
var buffet = e.values[12];    
var message = 'Kantine Rekvisition'+'<br>'

    +'Afdeling:        '+e.values[2]+'<br>'
    +'Afd. nr.:        '+e.values[3]+'<br>'
    +'Til dato/kl.:    '+e.values[8]+'<br>'+'<br>'

    **if (buffet!='') {
      +'Antal Buffet: '+ buffet + '<br>'**

    var body = message;
 var advancedArgs = {htmlBody:body, replyTo:email};
 MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, "Kantine Rekvisition", body, advancedArgs);
} catch(e){
 MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, "Error - Contact Us Form", e.message);
}
}
```

Comment: is that compiles right ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*blank*"? Is it `undefined`, or is it an empty string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use:

```
if (buffet) {
    // buffet is not undefined, null, false, 0 or empty string
}
```

Your existing condition `buffet!=''` should work as well, just keep in mind that `null!=''` is also truthy.

**Edit**

Btw, used inside a string concatenation, you should use the ternary operator:

```
var message = 'Kantine Rekvisition'+'<br>'
  +'Afdeling:        '+e.values[2]+'<br>'
  +'Afd. nr.:        '+e.values[3]+'<br>'
  +'Til dato/kl.:    '+e.values[8]+'<br>'+'<br>'
  +(buffet ? 'Antal Buffet: '+ buffet + '<br>' : '');
```

Comment: It does not work in my google scipt. I dont get the value from my variable Buffet, in my mail.

Comment: @user1734717 You don't get the value, because it's empty? I'm sure you want it to have a value but you should make sure; do a `console.log(buffet);` if you don't believe me :)

Comment: @user1734717 Perhaps I've missed something in your question; updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if variable is blank like this..

```
if(variable.length != 0){
   // not blank
}else{
   // blank
}
```